# what to expect from a face to face Data science interview, after taking an online aptitude test and an assignment

Tags: data-science

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, I applied for a data science job, I was given an aptitude test to complete and a data science question to solve, so three days ago, I was told to make myself available for a face to face interview. now am kind of confused I don't know what else to expect during the interview. any help, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is about programming-related questions. We do not offer career advice or help with interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect to be asked some basic domain questions
you be might be asked on my you choose this career path
if you have been giving an assignment you might be asked to explain it
they might test your soft skills